# Не создаются пакеты в пакете Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

знаю что закидаете тапками. Гуглил. Видимо еще не до конца освоил это дело. Копался, но не нашел. Когда пытаюсь создать пакет в пакете в intellij он просто добавляет в первому пакету имя второго через точку. Пару дней назад все создавалось нормально, сейчас не понимаю что такого произошло. Пример если есть пакет structure и я хочу создать  в нем пакет factory то первый пакет получит имя structure.factory. Как быть?

Спасибо большое тем кто откликнется.

Comment: idea сама сворачивает пакеты, в которых есть только один вложенный пакет. если вам требуется работать с пакетом уровнем выше, вы можете создать его в текущем пакете, нажать f6 и переместить.

Comment: Но как мне быть если мне в этом пакете надо создать два пакета?

Comment: *если вам требуется работать с пакетом уровнем выше, вы можете создать его в текущем пакете, нажать f6 и переместить.* я могу еще пару раз повторить, если нужно.

Answer (score 5):

В настройках проекта (чтобы вызвать нажимаете на боковую выпадающую вкладку "Project", затем на шестеренку) убираете галочку с пункта "Hide Empty Middle Packages".

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас немного иначе, также выбираем "Project" - "шестерёнка" - "Tree appearance" - "Compact middle packages (Убираем галочку)".